# Meaning of frequent contraction "iirc"

Tags: support

Relative newbie, sorry for the idiot question, but what does *iirc* in an answer/comment mean? Thank you.

Comment: Huh, I thought lmgtfy was blacklisted.

Comment: @Semaphore - Hmm. A quick search of meta does seem to indicate it is considered to be in bad taste. I've deleted the comment and told off the miscreant who wrote it.

Comment: @T.E.D. and Semaphore -   I did indicate I was a newbie, thank you for defending me from other's bad manners.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iirc - "if I remember correctly"/"if I recall correctly"

So it's basically shorthand for "I could be wrong" and, therefore, a caution that the statement that follows should not be treated as a verified 'fact'.

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/IIRC